# Vectorization to extract and bind very nested data

Tags: r, purrr

I have some very nested data. Within my list-column-dataframes, there are some pieces I need to put together and I've done so in a single instance to get my desired dataframe:

```
a <- df[[2]][["result"]]@data
b <- df[[2]][["result"]]@coords

desired_df <- cbind(a, b)
```

My original Large list has 171 elements, meaning I have 1:171 (3.3 GB) to go inside those square brackets and would ideally end up with 171 desired dataframes (which I would then bind all together).

I haven't needed to write a loop in 10 years, but I don't see a tidyverse way to deal with this. I also no longer know how to write loops. There are definitely some elements in there that are junk and will fail.

Comment: Any way you can provide some sample data?

Comment: I wish I could, but I'm unsure how to recreate the file structure and I'm not aware of any datasets with something similar. First time seeing an `@` for me.

Comment: One can't be sure what you have given the missing information in the question but this might work:  `sapply(c("data", "coords"), slot, object = df[[2]]$result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any sort of minimal example of the data.

I've condensed it to mean something like this

```r
base_data <- data.frame(group = c("a", "b", "c"), var1 = c(3, 1, 2), 
                  var2 = c( 2, 4, 8))  

base_data2 = matrix(
   c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
   nrow = 3,  
   ncol = 3,        
   byrow = TRUE         
)
rownames(base_data2) = c("d", "e", "f")

methods::setClass(
  "weird_object",
  slots = c(data = "data.frame", coords = "matrix"),
  prototype = list(data = base_data, coords = base_data2) 
)


df <- list(
  list(
    result = new("weird_object")
  ),list(
    result = new("weird_object")
  ),list(
    result = new("weird_object")
  ),list(
    result = new("weird_object")
  )
)
```

And if I had such a list with these objects, then I could do

```r
df %>% 
  map(. %>% {
    list(data = .$result@data,
         cooords = .$result@coords)
  }) %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  unnest_wider(value)
```

But the selecting / hoisting function might fail, thus
one can wrap it in a `purrr::possibly`, and
choose a reasonable default:

```r
df %>% 
  map(possibly(. %>% {
    list(data = .$result@data,
         cooords = .$result@coords)
  }, 
    otherwise = list(data = NA, coords = NA))) %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  unnest_wider(value)
```

Hopefully, this could be a step forward.

Next step is probably something resembling this:

```r
df %>%
  map(. %>% {
    list(data = .$result@data,
         coords = .$result@coords)
  }) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest_wider(value) %>%
  mutate(coords = coords %>% map(. %>% as_tibble(rownames = "rowid"))) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(data, coords)) %>%
  #' rotating the thing now

  pivot_longer(cols = c(group, rowid),
               names_to = "var_name",
               values_to = "var") %>%
  select(-var_name) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(var1, var2, V1, V2, V3),
               names_to = "var_name") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value) %>%
  identity()
```

Comment: I added in another layer and am currently working towards adding another unnest step. Ideally, we would end with a giant dataframe with only column headers a:f.

Comment: Added another suggestion.. But there is something very complicated that you're trying to do here.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your data structure, which I probably don't, you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create dummy data
df <- mtcars
df$mpg <- list(result = I(list('test')))
df$mpg$result <- list("@data" = I(list('your data')))
df <- df %>% select(mpg, cyl)
df1 <- df
df2 <- df

# Pull data you're interested in. 
# The index is 1 here, instead of 2, because it's fake data and not your data.
# Assuming the @ is not unique, and is just parsed from JSON or some other format.
dont_at_me <- function(x){
  a <- x[[1]][["result"]][["@data"]]
  a
}

# Get a list of all of your data.frames
all_dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

# Vectorize
purrr::map(all_dfs, ~dont_at_me(.))
```